# Python datetime utcnow() milliseconds to 9 digits?

Tags: python, datetime

I am attempting to format a datetime string to have the milliseconds represented as 9 digits. I cannot figure out how to do this without manipulating the whole string. I currently have

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

and I would like the milliseconds (%f) printed as 9 digits, instead of the default 6. How do I do this?

Just to clarify, I don't need 9 digit precision, I just need to print, for example, 2013-07-19 09:28:00.000544913 with the three padded 0's.

Comment: Milliseconds means thousandths of a second. So there's only 3 digits in a millisecond. What you're printing are microseconds; there are only 6 digits in a microsecond.

Comment: If you just want to pad it out with 0's, of course, you can do that: `'%Y-%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f000'`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks, you sent me in the right direction, I now have datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000%f')!

Comment: Why are you padding with *leading* zeros? That's like wanting to display one and a half as 1.0005.

Comment: @Rothschild, you're doing thins wrong. _Physically_ wrong. You're getting an incorrect representation of your time!

Comment: @Rothschild: no, that's almost certainly not what you want. That will turn 1.2 seconds into 1.0002 seconds, etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m%d %H:%M:%S.000%f')
```

Seems to work for me.

Physically you should do this to get the correct representation of the time:

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f000')
```

Comment: No, this is wrong. You want to put the three extra 0's at the end; otherwise you're dividing the fraction by 1000.

Comment: But you know that you are now lying to yourself, right? If you want 9 digits for some reason then add the padding at the other end.

Comment: I may be mixing things up, but `000%f` nanoseconds is not the same as `%f` microseconds. 1 microsecond is 1000 nanoseconds and not the other way around. You're are displaying an incorrect time as far as I know. To make it right you should add the zeros to the right.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the output Rothschild want. Personally I also feel that adding the zeroes to the right makes more sense.

Comment: This is for a problem task. For some reason, the time stamps are in that format. Every single one of them has three zeros padded on the left.

Answer (score 3):

First, milliseconds to 9 digits wouldn't make any sense. The "milli" means "thousandths", as in 3 digits.

Second, you don't have milliseconds, you have microseconds. The `datetime` type has a `microseconds` attribute, and `%f` is defined as microseconds. And of course "micro" means "millionths", as in 6 digits.

Since there are no nanoseconds being stored in the object, it wouldn't make much sense to have a nanoseconds format specifier. But, if there were a nanoseconds format specifier, it would just be the microseconds with an extra three 0's at the end, which you can just do yourself:

```
'%Y-%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f000'
```

Alternatively, nobody's forcing you to use `strfime`; you could always use `str.format` and include a `{:09}` field and pass `dt.microseconds * 1000` to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). According to it, the precision is offered up to microsend (which is what you have), not nanosecond (which is what you want).

Comment: Let me clarify my question. I just want to pad '000' to the end of that particular part of the string. I have a string '2013-07-19 09:28:00.000123456', which I assume is microseconds, just with the padded 0s.

Comment: Let me clarify the answer: By 'padding' after the decimal point, you are reducing the size of the number to the right of the 'padding' by three orders of magnitude, so going from microseconds to nanoseconds. To clarify further - padding only works if you add it *before* any digits. You can't just insert digits into a number and expect the number to still be the same

Comment: @SiHa: If you're trying to pad out a real number (like `%S.%f`) you want the padding _after_ the digits, not _before_ if you want the same number.

Comment: @ abarnert: I should have been clearer: You can add the padding before *any* digits for any real number (00001.2 = 1.2, yes?). If you're on the RHS of the decimal point, then I agree, they have to go at the end (1.2 = 1.2000)

Answer (score -1):

```
strtime1 = '2022-06-21T08:38:09.602121578Z'
strtime1= strtime1[:-4]+strtime1[-1]
strtime2= datetime.datetime.strptime(strtime1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
print(strtime1,strtime2)
```

Comment: Hey Adams, welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be beneficial if you could explain the code in your answer and what makes it different from the years of existing answers to this question.